# Selenium Button Click() or Submit()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need help on following scenario(using Java):

Doing it manually like this: after filling in some info in a parent page, clicking Continue button on it,

```
<INPUT TYPE='button' VALUE='Continue' onClick='sendForm()'>
```

A child window(UserConfirmationPage) pops up with those info from its parent window, clicking the Continue button on the child page, posting the data to server.

```
<FORM NAME='userConf' ACTION='user.jsp' METHOD='post'> 
Do you want to continue?<BR>
<INPUT TYPE='button' VALUE='Continue' onClick='createUser()'> 
</FORM>
```

However, when I do it using Selenium Web Driver, on the parent page,

```
btnContinue.submit()
```

a child page pops up with those info from parent page just like what I got when I do it manually but parent does not exist any more. While using

```
btnContinue.click()
```

a blank child page is opened without getting any info from parent page and it also complains "session is lost".

I also tried:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",btnContinue);
```

and

```
 new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue']"))).click().perform();
```

but nothing works.

It seems that neither Submit() nor Click() could simulate what was done manually. Any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: This does not look like Java. Did you mean JavaScript? The two are very different.

Comment: I use Java to develop test cases but web application itself uses JavaScript and JSP as you can see from the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the language, so I assume you're using JAVA:

```
// since new tab has been opened - need to switch to this tab
// get a list of the currently open windows
Set<String> allTabs = driver.getWindowHandles();

// save the window handle for the current window
String programTab = driver.getWindowHandle();

// switching to the Save tab
String saveTab = ((String) allTabs.toArray()[1]);
driver.switchTo().window(saveTab);
// set timeout

// Click button
driver.findElement(By.id("buttonId")).click();
// set timeout

// switch back to the program tab
driver.switchTo().window(programTab);
```

Comment: sorry, first time post. I should have provided more detailed info. Just updated the question, so can you please shed some light on it?

Comment: @Andrew not sure what else can I add there. As far as I understand, you have 2 windows or tabs and you need to switch between them. Since you have 'driver' object, use the code I posted and see if it works. Add some timeouts where it's indicated if needed.

Comment: Let me clarify more, the child window(a separate  window, not a new tab) was generated by clicking the Continue button on the parent page. While clicking on the Continue button on the child page is supposed to  close the child window/page and run a jsp script to create a user.  It is totally ok when doing it manually. But Selenium webdriver's clicking on the button in the child window/page does not do anything.  I am just wondering how to use webdriver to deal with this.

Comment: @Andrew Alright, the code above should work for windows too. Are you sure that your Webdriver actually switches to the child window and clicks on Continue? Maybe try to get that child page's title as a test to make sure Webdriver actually switches to child. If Webdriver switches to child but does not click on Continue, try adding some timeouts to wait until your child page is fully rendered, perhaps Continue is invisible at the time when Webdriver tries to click on it?

Comment: it does switch to the child page since I can grab some text from the html body on the child page. The button on the child page was clearly clicked because I can see that the color of the button was changed to blue and it was clicked. Timeout does not help either. I think it is related to how Webdriver interacts with the post action on a child page.

Comment: Alright, another idea. Since you're sure you're on the child page, try using JavascriptExecutor and click on the button using Javascript code instead of using Webdriver. You can find bunch of examples online, let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping helpping me! . Yes, I tried:   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",btnContinue);
  
 or new Actions(driver).moveToElement(btnContinue).sendKeys (Keys.ENTER).perform(); nothing works so far.

Comment: you're welcome! At this point I have no more ideas except this: since your webdriver seems to click on the Continue button and nothing happens, it might be worth checking if there are any JS errors are being thrown or checking how Network requests are going. For this you would have to enable DEV tools if it's running in Chrome or Firebug in FF. I am not sure if it's easy, but if it is - worth trying, this will certainly might give a clue.

Comment: it seems to me that it is more related to submit() vs click() in Parent and child window. I will try to work with developer to see if the trace can be turned on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is simplest and easiest code which help you to understand Parent and child scenario.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/popup.php");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p/a")).click();

// return the parent window name as a String
String parentWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Pass a window handle to the other window
for(String childWindow: driver.getWindowHandles())
{
System.out.println("child");

//switch to child window
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);

//find an element and print text of it 
WebElement textLabel=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/h2"));
System.out.println(" text:  "+textLabel.getText());
driver.close();
}

System.out.println("Come to parent window");

//switch to Parent window
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);

//find an element and print text of it 
 WebElement logotext=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/h2"));
 System.out.println("text: "+logotext.getText());

driver.close();
}
```

Comment: It does seem to have any problem switching to a child page.

Comment: what problem u face?

Comment: Just update the original post,  It seems that neither button.click() nor button.submit() works on the parent page.