# Parent/Child: Submit() or Click()?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have been struggling finding a solution for following scenario for several days now and hope someone can provide some help on this. Let me explain, if I do it manually, on a parent page, after filling some info, click the Continue button.

```
<FORM NAME='user' ACTION="userConf.jsp" METHOD='post'>
    <FIELDSET><LEGEND>Enter User Information</LEGEND>

   <INPUT TYPE='button' VALUE='Continue' onClick='sendForm()'>
```

a child page popups(while the parent page is still opened in the background), after reviewing the info from parent page, click the continue button o the child page.

```
 <FORM NAME='userConf' ACTION='user.jsp' METHOD='post'> 
    Do you want to continue?<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE='button' VALUE='Continue' onClick='createUser()'> 
  </FORM>
```

info will be posted to server through jsp, closing an Alert window(that says "A user has been created." will return to parent page.

While using Selenium WebDriver with Java, if I use btnContinue.click() on the parent page, a blank child window pops up without any info from parent and then application complains "Your session has been lost". If I use btnContinue.submit() or FormElement.submit(),  a child window pops up with info from parent page(just like what I get when I do it manually) but parent window is gone.  And clicking(using .click() or .submit()) the Continue button on child page does not do anything to create the user even I can tell it was click. I guess it is because the parent page does not exist any more at that moment.

Tried everything to click the Continue button on the parent page like:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",btnContinue);
  or 
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='Continue']"))).click().perform();
```

Nothing works so far. Really appreciate if someone can tell me how to simulate the manual clicking using Selenium Driver and Java.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: In your HTML find the source code for sendForm and post the details here. It may have to do with how the sendForm function is written

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Button Click() or Submit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702103/selenium-button-click-or-submit)

Comment: @Tarun, Here is the code:  function.sendForm(){
  if (checkFields()) {
    openConfirm();
    document.user.target="userConfirm"; 
    document.user.submit();                                                                                                                  function openConfirm() {
 win2 = window.open("","userConfirm",'toolbar,width=430,height=445,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
}
  }
}

Comment: Can anyone help me on this? Thanks a lot in advance!